# How to convert an Excel worksheet to HTML with style included

Tags: node.js, styles, xlsx

I am currently using the 'xlsx' package:

```
const XLSX = require('xlsx');
```

and converting my worksheet to an html table using:

```
var table = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_html(sheet).toString()
```

but it is a black and white table without any style from the original sheet.

How can I convert my excel file to HTML while retaining the original formatting (e.g., bold, text color, etc...)?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new html file with your worksheet and then style it using CSS. Use `xlsx.writeFile()` method to do that. It will create a new table from your xlsx file and then save it to your local directory.

Answer (score 0):

Ive used Aspose cells free version and it pretty much does the job without manipulating your stlyes.
You can use [Aspose cells](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aspose.cells) Aspose Library for this.

```
var aspose = aspose;

// get the aspose.cells module into your Node.js project.
aspose.cells = require("aspose.cells");

// create an instance Workbook  and load the source Excel file   
var workbook = aspose.cells.Workbook("yourExcel.xlsx");

// save the file in HTML format 
workbook.save("newFile.html",options);
```

Give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

**Revised:**

```
from xlsx2html import xlsx2html

xlsx2html('book.xlsx', 'output.html')
```

**Output:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKhk4.jpg

Comment: This function doesn't seem to exist. Can you [edit] the answer with a link to its documentation?

Comment: Revised. https://pypi.org/project/xlsx2html/#description